# How to design an input field for creating React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with  **React 18.2.0**. I want to design an input field like the below image, in which user can add multiple chips, and then save those chips and pass them to the backend project.
[image]
I have seen this component in `<Autocomplete>` tag section in **material-UI**:
[image]

But I don't want to have any predefined options with a select menu, and just want to let the users to type any thing that they want, and create a new chip after pressing on Enter button.

In the other words a `<TextField>` which let the users to create multiple chips.

I have also tried the [material-ui-chip-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-chip-input) package, but after I click on enter button, the other buttons of my page would be modified, and the `<ChipInput />` can not be well modified, and it is for older versions of **material-UI**. And I am searching for a better way to implement something like this.
I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a wrapper div with an unstyled input element inside. Add a listener to your input field which will create a new chip when Enter is pressed, and clear the input. The chips will be placed on a row inside the wrapper, while the input field will be pushet to the right as more and more items are added.

```
const MultiChipInput = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const addItem = (event) => {
    if (event.code === "Enter") {
      let _items = [...items];
      _items.push(event.target.value);

      setItems(_items);
      setInputValue("");
    }
  };

  const removeItem = (item) => {
    const _items = items.filter((x) => x !== item);
    setItems(_items);
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div className="chip">
          {item}
          <span onClick={() => removeItem(item)}>x</span>
        </div>
      ))}
      <input
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        className={"myInput"}
        onKeyDown={addItem}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.myInput {
  all: unset;
}

.chip {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.chip > span {
  margin-left: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: May you please send a code example?